# HMSegmentedControl (custom tab bar controller) switching subviews feature

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I'm looking for a way to use [HMSegmentedControl](https://github.com/HeshamMegid/HMSegmentedControl) inside a `UINavigationController`, using the tabs to change the subview. That is clicking on a tab should display the corresponding view below the `UINavigationBar` and the `HMSegmentedControl` tabs. If possible, using as much as Storyboard features as possible.

I have made several attempts, by inserting the views as outlets. The further I got is to have it running by using when detecting a tab selection change (and removing the other subviews obviously):

```
insertSubview:(UIView *) belowSubview:(UIView *)
```

but it cuts the upper part of the subview (the one overlapping with the `HMSegmentedControl` tabs bar) and also makes the non-initial views not behaving well in terms of autosizing (for instance when rotating the screen).

Are there best practices for implementing such custom upper tab bar controllers inside a navigation controller (and not the opposite because of another dependency I am using)? Or better yet is there an easy way to do what I am trying to do using Storyboards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is better to juggle controllers than views.

I would have several controllers with identical navigation bars. That is an identical `HMSegmentedControl` in their bars.

As the user changes the selected segment you switch controllers and make sure to adjust both the exiting and entering controller's segment control state accordingly.

---

You could also try to have all navigationItems to point to the same `HMSegmentedControl` instance and see if it works.

Comment: I basically went with a solution with hidden subviews with proper constraints set. Indeed, a somehow heavy HTTP request fetching possibly heavy and paginated data was to be received for both views (similar request) and having it either send the request again or pass the data around would be sub-optimal for my case (I should have mentionned that probably).
I belive your first option would be the way to go for my initial question so I'll accept the answer, thanks !